# Python - Remove Braces and Commas from a Tuple CSV File

Tags: python, csv

I'm printing out to a csv file like this:

```
bdictionary = ## bdictionary is a big list of tuples
w = csv.writer(open("testnucsv.csv", "w"))
for sent in bdictionary:
    w.writerow(sent)
```

And it prints out perfectly fine and looks like this:

> (u'My', u'D') (u'dog', u'N')............... 
>   (u'The', u'D') ............................

How can I print it out like this

> My D dog N
>   The D

This is what I tried, and it isn't working. It splits up every charachter:

```
w = csv.writer(open("testnucsv.csv", "w"))
for sent in bdictionary:
    sent = ''.join(str(v) for v in sent)
    w.writerow(sent)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in a list, writerow expects an iterable so it iterates over your string splitting it into single characters:

```
sent = [' '.join(" ".join(v) for v in sent)]
```

You also need to join the strings in the tuple as above not call str on the tuple i.e:

```
t = [(u'My', u'D'), (u'dog', u'N')]

print(" ".join([" ".join(v) for v in t]))
My D dog N
```

You could also just use file.write and pass it the joined string:

```
with open("testnucsv.csv", "w") as f:
   for sent in bdictionary:
        f.write(" ".join([" ".join(v) for v in sent])+"\n")
```

Comment: The last block of code isn't compiling for me. Invalid Syntax

Comment: Thanks, it worked with the very first block of code, which is what I was using, but I checked your 3rd one and thought I'd let you know it didn't compile for me. Thanks!